# Need to know battery configuration for a 250 watts inverter

Tags: batteries, inverter, ups

I have  a 12 Volt inverter which have ability to produce 250 W output. I would like to purchase a battery for this. can any one tell me the configuration of battery ?
eg: Minimum AH

Comment: How long do you want to run it for taking 250W and what is the circuit of the inverter?

Comment: I don't know the circuit of the inverter because I just purchased it from shop. and if I use full load I need to work this for minimum 1 hr.

Comment: What battery did the shop recommend?

Comment: That is the funny thing he is just a seller and he don't know about battery rating.!

Comment: How about a link to the inverter then?

Comment: Sorry for a link because it is a local made one.

Comment: Do you know the converter's power efficiency then? What about the top and bottom limits for the battery voltage i.e. it works from 11V to 15V or something like that. If you don't know these things why did you buy it? Also, in your title it says 25W not 250W

Comment: Ah! Sorry for that I just updated my title. Low limit is 10 v AND maximum is 13.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ball park figure calculation.

Assuming an 80% efficiency

```
              Power in = 100/80 x power out
```

**power out** will be 250W (maximum) then required **power in** will be about 313 watts

By Ohm's law this gives a figure of 313/12 Amps i.e. 26Amps

So if you need to run for 1 hour this would suggest you need a battery of at least 26 Amp hr rating.

Comment: @user2827944 - don't forget that if you want to use  the inverter for an hour and you buy the 26 amp hour battery, you will completely drain the battery.  This is a really bad thing to do to lead acid batteries.  If you want the battery to last then you want to drain it only 50% on average so get a 52amp hour battery.